# what could affect the value returned by $(window).width()?

Tags: jquery

I have an application which uses jQuery to hide/show a panel. Here's an aspx version which shows the principle:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ClickMe').click(function () {
            $('#Panel').toggle();
            $('#Width').text($(window).width());
        });
        $('#Width').text($(window).width());
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <fieldset id="FS1">
        <legend id="ClickMe">Click Me</legend>
        <div id="Panel" style="display:;width:auto">
            <label for="A">A</label>
            <input id="A" name="A" type="text" value="" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <span id="Width">0</span>
</asp:Content>
```

This works as expected. $(window).width() always returns the same value.

In the application, the value returned initially or when 'Panel' is hidden is correct, but when it's visible, the value returned is 17 pixels less.

What could affect the value returned by jQuery?

Comment: Is a vertical scrollbar making the difference?

Comment: No scrollbars are visible. When initially displayed the page is correct, it's only after hiding the panel that it's wrong. I need to try to put together a page which shows he problem (and doesn't need dozens of support files). Of course, in doing that I might find out where the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, it is probably a scrollbar that'a making a difference. To calculate a width without a scrollbar you would have to force the body to hide them while you do the calculation. Something like this:

```
//hide the scrollbars
$('body').css({overflow: 'hidden'});
//get the window width here
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
//and now we put the scrollbars back
$('body').css({overflow: 'auto'});
```

Comment: No scrollbars are visible but I'll try your suggestion next week.